# Why we find out the initial feasible solution for transportation problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I saw several methods that available to obtain an initial basic feasible solution of a transportation problem.

```
Method:1 North-West Corner Rule(NWC),

Method:2 Least Cost Method (LCM),

Method:3 Vogel’s Approximation Method(VAM)

etc,....
```

Why do we have so many methods?  Why we need initial feasible solution? I mean , why not using Simplex method?
After gaining one feasible solution, then we do what?

Comment: Doesn't the simplex method also require an initial feasible solution?

Comment: Well By using artificial variable, we have it.